# How do I read the "frequency" (first column) and "Ant In Fwd"(third column) TableValues from the txt file below and store them in an array?

Tags: python

[getting data from txt file, the needed data is in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trqnp.png)

[the list of elements is very long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qX4e.png)

[ERROR given the code from Claudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIjlo.png)

[Thank you Claudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A8vm.png)

The input is the data starting with [FileInfo].
The output is the data in a 2 X (very long) array inside python (not a file) for further use to make a graph (2 dimensional x y). The output is the table below

| Frequency | Ant In Fwd |
| --- | --- |
| 20.00000000000E+0 | 276.18112860E+0 |
| 20.50000000000E+0 | 307.54523316E+0 |
| ... | ... |

Very bad example code, sorry for lack of knowledge, Im a newbie student. Function that reads a file line by line stores it into an array.

```
def file_read(fname):
        content_array = []
        with open(fname) as f:
                #Content_list is the list that contains the read lines.     
                for line in f:
                        content_array.append(line)
                print(content_array)

file_read('test.txt')
```

```
[FileInfo]
Author=EMC32
Version=8.3
MeasClass=0 <No Class>
Start=20.00000000000E+6
Stop=80.00000000000E+6

[TurnTable]
Azimuth=0.0000000000E+0

[TableSettings]
TableType= 49 Result Table
IndicateDetector=1
Columns=11
Rows= 121
SaveResolution=0
BandsOption=0
ResultType= 0

[TableHeader]
Name=   Frequency   Imm Level-Pk/H  Ant In Fwd  Ant In Rev  VSWR    Gen Out Comment Modulation  Polarization    Height  Azimuth
Unit=   MHz V/m W   W       dBm             m   deg
ColTyp= 11 Frequency    18 Immunity Level   22 Transducer Level 13 Level    23 Meas Value   17 Generator Level  0 Text  0 Text  5 Polarization  27 Position 28 Azimuth
Detector=    0   3   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0   0
Intpol=  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Format=  6   2   3   3   3   1   0   0   0   2   1
ColWidth=   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
ColVisible= 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
ColReport=  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

[TableValues]
20.00000000000E+0   71.361716627E+0 276.18112860E+0 251.19327026E+0 42.186747983E+0 -5.4734012735E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
20.50000000000E+0   71.633896749E+0 307.54523316E+0 253.53271081E+0 20.727601924E+0 -5.7709953921E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
21.00000000000E+0   71.508344980E+0 342.74884502E+0 257.05555887E+0 13.927063094E+0 -5.4372383372E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
21.50000000000E+0   71.563696353E+0 380.91142586E+0 265.75105665E+0 11.140883256E+0 -4.9133552299E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
22.00000000000E+0   71.691399647E+0 419.46526145E+0 280.91569223E+0 10.010288726E+0 -4.7424914652E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
22.50000000000E+0   71.045903502E+0 446.71239183E+0 298.41249241E+0 9.9483737020E+0 -4.7424914652E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
23.00000000000E+0   70.457828027E+0 457.14713254E+0 316.83999663E+0 10.941358695E+0 -4.0095055528E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
23.50000000000E+0   71.299810538E+0 445.55364407E+0 327.76003702E+0 13.053368515E+0 -2.9079669061E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
24.00000000000E+0   70.370069530E+0 387.30936661E+0 304.71792339E+0 16.697957146E+0 -2.9079669061E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
24.50000000000E+0   71.679131834E+0 319.64432623E+0 265.41043880E+0 21.528797825E+0 -3.7767875786E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
25.00000000000E+0   71.864266350E+0 244.65888941E+0 208.36942822E+0 24.927370032E+0 -5.7046243101E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
25.50000000000E+0   71.720232666E+0 198.29465134E+0 169.78643908E+0 25.784027435E+0 -7.9685914943E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
26.00000000000E+0   71.585540379E+0 179.98611383E+0 153.28723836E+0 24.925227522E+0 -9.3177729467E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
26.50000000000E+0   71.567938283E+0 180.56476209E+0 151.86650557E+0 23.124104461E+0 -8.7606694612E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
27.00000000000E+0   70.906930770E+0 187.95331936E+0 152.65885476E+0 19.249216630E+0 -7.1788162495E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
27.50000000000E+0   70.810389761E+0 204.93304827E+0 157.43127039E+0 15.191045693E+0 -5.9000880719E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
28.00000000000E+0   71.369027205E+0 229.36703471E+0 164.53072067E+0 12.067662864E+0 -5.4356907864E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
28.50000000000E+0   71.749089443E+0 255.05685484E+0 169.75633878E+0 9.8589591809E+0 -5.8938019003E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
29.00000000000E+0   71.423208317E+0 275.11356206E+0 170.47001525E+0 8.3971286959E+0 -6.9650709315E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
29.50000000000E+0   71.674423996E+0 296.39167426E+0 173.45107667E+0 7.5102596975E+0 -7.7983168745E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
30.00000000000E+0   71.608984357E+0 310.54389797E+0 175.65236437E+0 7.0672007142E+0 -7.6283644406E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
30.50000000000E+0   70.488185548E+0 309.11636660E+0 177.80542191E+0 7.2789341393E+0 -6.5449942800E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
31.00000000000E+0   70.904206996E+0 318.64051843E+0 187.18756721E+0 7.5637467146E+0 -5.4080905704E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
31.50000000000E+0   70.846225343E+0 321.71847396E+0 196.90919649E+0 8.1886020983E+0 -4.7475444666E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
32.00000000000E+0   70.655419460E+0 316.03559512E+0 208.24855663E+0 9.6242441131E+0 -4.7475444666E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
32.50000000000E+0   71.719833217E+0 325.35388729E+0 233.12454418E+0 12.027502545E+0 -5.0296510810E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
33.00000000000E+0   71.629569099E+0 325.79768947E+0 251.68190935E+0 15.518737114E+0 -5.7874324644E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
33.50000000000E+0   71.749978231E+0 330.26382010E+0 271.64767981E+0 20.488590303E+0 -6.5670576335E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
34.00000000000E+0   71.594062879E+0 336.15919882E+0 287.17392235E+0 25.410461502E+0 -6.8380248354E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
34.50000000000E+0   71.181608763E+0 343.34837792E+0 296.48996581E+0 27.272766842E+0 -5.9328749883E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
35.00000000000E+0   70.363014246E+0 349.34055027E+0 297.49659543E+0 24.913093593E+0 -4.3342134938E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
35.50000000000E+0   71.255759677E+0 375.30383308E+0 307.84705266E+0 20.204983728E+0 -2.8090871118E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
36.00000000000E+0   70.981279382E+0 387.45654367E+0 302.58333134E+0 16.198753669E+0 -2.4177844549E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
36.50000000000E+0   72.054871758E+0 413.09696096E+0 300.56887098E+0 12.604891178E+0 -2.8543483629E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
37.00000000000E+0   71.829457831E+0 419.93783027E+0 284.10050127E+0 10.268518609E+0 -4.1498338757E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
37.50000000000E+0   72.088839519E+0 428.21019210E+0 269.52868970E+0 8.6789847916E+0 -5.7185594599E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
38.00000000000E+0   71.876173591E+0 422.87206838E+0 248.87197827E+0 7.5894297347E+0 -6.6103204424E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
38.50000000000E+0   71.173236934E+0 406.56220208E+0 225.85567115E+0 6.8534801733E+0 -5.8949060249E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
39.00000000000E+0   70.790912448E+0 390.52514291E+0 208.21163763E+0 6.4122596830E+0 -4.4078081777E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
39.50000000000E+0   70.515938921E+0 372.79149874E+0 194.70540157E+0 6.2123164069E+0 -3.4188872702E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
40.00000000000E+0   71.374051725E+0 364.50626734E+0 190.76117991E+0 6.2312674625E+0 -3.2018460165E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
40.50000000000E+0   72.043080782E+0 353.49965966E+0 189.63129025E+0 6.4744145495E+0 -3.9080826627E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
41.00000000000E+0   71.917920427E+0 337.30361834E+0 188.90610782E+0 6.9479672671E+0 -5.2734600970E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
41.50000000000E+0   71.646478552E+0 324.26867725E+0 190.02030026E+0 7.5289324155E+0 -6.6261638348E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
42.00000000000E+0   71.794240983E+0 317.28679661E+0 194.54810280E+0 8.2185612291E+0 -7.2471374070E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
42.50000000000E+0   71.597514578E+0 311.35869620E+0 196.79316025E+0 8.7567397813E+0 -6.8442883342E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
43.00000000000E+0   71.146059148E+0 306.50460228E+0 196.59207201E+0 9.0439202025E+0 -5.8297529966E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
43.50000000000E+0   70.972556522E+0 305.75671236E+0 195.06214697E+0 8.9367647839E+0 -4.8639811590E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
44.00000000000E+0   71.177303696E+0 307.16589939E+0 191.18948352E+0 8.4761027140E+0 -4.3701782579E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
44.50000000000E+0   72.758058280E+0 319.76505438E+0 191.17715748E+0 7.8190797705E+0 -4.3701782579E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
45.00000000000E+0   71.795535460E+0 309.79471175E+0 173.94141552E+0 6.9781439318E+0 -5.3109594839E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
45.50000000000E+0   71.700201560E+0 303.73790981E+0 158.20018973E+0 6.1863733132E+0 -6.5362996014E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
46.00000000000E+0   71.794783925E+0 296.18973284E+0 140.57497016E+0 5.4292211392E+0 -7.5590895807E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
46.50000000000E+0   71.557065132E+0 283.90954912E+0 120.32891480E+0 4.7310039244E+0 -7.3756541508E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
47.00000000000E+0   71.577119604E+0 273.09641557E+0 101.63165551E+0 4.1286976696E+0 -6.0935445592E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
47.50000000000E+0   71.257236590E+0 262.03119653E+0 83.343742828E+0 3.5868949627E+0 -4.8699053134E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
48.00000000000E+0   71.482587274E+0 259.99619967E+0 68.018492125E+0 3.0940114588E+0 -4.2408372572E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
48.50000000000E+0   71.425938520E+0 271.97313040E+0 54.233920480E+0 2.6137120627E+0 -4.2408372572E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
49.00000000000E+0   71.346300309E+0 323.31064203E+0 42.712599155E+0 2.1420333661E+0 -4.2408372572E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
49.50000000000E+0   71.224697473E+0 438.66905593E+0 35.633132274E+0 1.7972378163E+0 -3.4575457846E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
50.00000000000E+0   71.580439500E+0 506.88565413E+0 39.704707411E+0 1.7773003143E+0 -3.1107021791E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
50.50000000000E+0   71.492183862E+0 427.79135115E+0 47.207717202E+0 1.9948773423E+0 -3.9779305215E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
51.00000000000E+0   71.676295479E+0 347.23780321E+0 51.696483202E+0 2.2565263321E+0 -4.5616084760E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
51.50000000000E+0   71.662125193E+0 298.00805295E+0 53.725071235E+0 2.4758104700E+0 -4.7763695012E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
52.00000000000E+0   71.764579744E+0 270.10212440E+0 54.369207167E+0 2.6274926856E+0 -5.0312651272E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
52.50000000000E+0   71.886473443E+0 253.26431389E+0 53.508281110E+0 2.7012774189E+0 -5.5339989999E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
53.00000000000E+0   71.959844978E+0 241.52161275E+0 51.046150902E+0 2.7018575291E+0 -6.2127695145E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
53.50000000000E+0   71.881817448E+0 230.94842243E+0 46.825023068E+0 2.6382078769E+0 -6.8983579939E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
54.00000000000E+0   71.768689101E+0 221.12660594E+0 41.106452628E+0 2.5159028307E+0 -7.4158734773E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
54.50000000000E+0   71.677341468E+0 211.77612623E+0 34.206607153E+0 2.3439146282E+0 -7.7487301104E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
55.00000000000E+0   72.543994063E+0 207.62469142E+0 27.503502270E+0 2.1444598188E+0 -7.7487301104E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
55.50000000000E+0   71.754948783E+0 194.39316914E+0 19.727951883E+0 1.9349905051E+0 -7.7487301104E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
56.00000000000E+0   70.419848478E+0 179.17606725E+0 12.896474389E+0 1.7333025761E+0 -7.7487301104E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
56.50000000000E+0   70.407020418E+0 170.96412977E+0 8.1111045616E+0 1.5569393880E+0 -7.7487301104E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
57.00000000000E+0   72.564834919E+0 173.28341569E+0 5.3556970159E+0 1.4266081546E+0 -7.7487301104E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
57.50000000000E+0   71.708639484E+0 160.65564867E+0 3.8212372266E+0 1.3646943288E+0 -8.3387398897E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
58.00000000000E+0   71.698012616E+0 152.11953879E+0 3.8085091208E+0 1.3759419868E+0 -8.7558957041E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
58.50000000000E+0   72.829301867E+0 148.08190747E+0 4.4896656515E+0 1.4216679518E+0 -8.7558957041E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
59.00000000000E+0   72.891316246E+0 140.00450164E+0 4.6898613120E+0 1.4480535385E+0 -8.7558957041E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
59.50000000000E+0   72.491465271E+0 132.55618607E+0 4.0514548180E+0 1.4237306212E+0 -8.9711762853E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
60.00000000000E+0   71.638429739E+0 127.48790957E+0 2.9672285567E+0 1.3600494020E+0 -9.1386888386E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
60.50000000000E+0   70.762023896E+0 126.92904135E+0 2.1440010810E+0 1.2987625150E+0 -9.1386888386E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
61.00000000000E+0   70.825244039E+0 132.86787829E+0 1.9129164418E+0 1.2726964138E+0 -8.7772517766E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
61.50000000000E+0   71.543288033E+0 143.70173114E+0 2.1196785255E+0 1.2764829843E+0 -8.3615079700E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
62.00000000000E+0   71.402734506E+0 152.22115048E+0 2.4028352805E+0 1.2873847520E+0 -7.9965484581E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
62.50000000000E+0   71.459587965E+0 162.15860515E+0 2.5657243743E+0 1.2877713976E+0 -7.5877824576E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
63.00000000000E+0   71.445314288E+0 171.88223808E+0 2.4827500540E+0 1.2732056860E+0 -7.2089502736E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
63.50000000000E+0   71.527662662E+0 182.25690877E+0 2.2382005597E+0 1.2492564947E+0 -6.8746404724E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
64.00000000000E+0   71.429178829E+0 192.06976278E+0 2.0626949247E+0 1.2312229682E+0 -6.5780316421E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
64.50000000000E+0   71.550465516E+0 203.99710301E+0 2.3370876476E+0 1.2397292470E+0 -6.2835875894E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
65.00000000000E+0   71.533119273E+0 216.24844837E+0 3.4316975132E+0 1.2882592305E+0 -6.0227712379E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
65.50000000000E+0   71.524779594E+0 230.12722472E+0 5.6937972719E+0 1.3733118824E+0 -5.8090231431E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
66.00000000000E+0   71.595217608E+0 245.97275192E+0 9.3832437887E+0 1.4854410062E+0 -5.6133790018E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
66.50000000000E+0   71.507446285E+0 262.07584817E+0 14.618943917E+0 1.6184205278E+0 -5.3227725760E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
67.00000000000E+0   71.483067801E+0 280.23024081E+0 21.371401333E+0 1.7630372501E+0 -4.8001993550E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
67.50000000000E+0   71.540190638E+0 300.26450761E+0 29.453980842E+0 1.9120505500E+0 -4.1152962201E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
68.00000000000E+0   71.536899020E+0 320.66975502E+0 38.261588800E+0 2.0554129363E+0 -3.5312536898E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
68.50000000000E+0   71.598106047E+0 341.56471502E+0 47.327547496E+0 2.1859198824E+0 -3.2483042073E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
69.00000000000E+0   72.349233654E+0 369.62726601E+0 57.030345155E+0 2.2938052910E+0 -3.2483042073E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
69.50000000000E+0   71.872776578E+0 384.50854885E+0 63.725903269E+0 2.3732709133E+0 -3.6418622796E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
70.00000000000E+0   71.683821238E+0 401.63448964E+0 69.177521818E+0 2.4189089892E+0 -3.8803053044E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
70.50000000000E+0   71.599887366E+0 419.44884224E+0 72.967253560E+0 2.4310315661E+0 -3.6406635854E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
71.00000000000E+0   71.453425038E+0 435.51488211E+0 74.486745612E+0 2.4104056504E+0 -2.9676382097E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
71.50000000000E+0   71.291992369E+0 451.55847742E+0 75.035365095E+0 2.3763209656E+0 -2.2616111734E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
72.00000000000E+0   71.481858490E+0 471.04131420E+0 75.163673955E+0 2.3303421637E+0 -1.8941898665E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
72.50000000000E+0   72.383024090E+0 502.24659371E+0 77.306497984E+0 2.2912501839E+0 -1.8941898665E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
73.00000000000E+0   71.632049924E+0 511.30495330E+0 77.274997556E+0 2.2720272347E+0 -2.3977758143E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
73.50000000000E+0   71.699397841E+0 530.14052032E+0 81.431230982E+0 2.2890534776E+0 -2.7804583408E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
74.00000000000E+0   72.568104141E+0 562.73120675E+0 91.173998183E+0 2.3473795867E+0 -2.7804583408E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
74.50000000000E+0   70.941209440E+0 558.67983988E+0 98.194915331E+0 2.4437649914E+0 -2.7804583408E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
75.00000000000E+0   71.317787606E+0 584.03382431E+0 114.84312458E+0 2.5934939440E+0 -2.2911512498E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
75.50000000000E+0   70.954624297E+0 597.21127726E+0 132.93581424E+0 2.7864372351E+0 -1.7285427531E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
76.00000000000E+0   70.774817496E+0 609.57338961E+0 153.74960192E+0 3.0178391714E+0 -1.1808139648E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
76.50000000000E+0   71.200163987E+0 626.86352429E+0 177.92582982E+0 3.2804710589E+0 -839.57927389E-3        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
77.00000000000E+0   71.397408092E+0 633.35616169E+0 199.61400119E+0 3.5599513133E+0 -839.57927389E-3        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
77.50000000000E+0   71.827184637E+0 639.58754805E+0 220.40020798E+0 3.8428987000E+0 -1.0273980618E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
78.00000000000E+0   72.187337859E+0 644.93804976E+0 238.77453062E+0 4.1080891683E+0 -1.4046938870E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
78.50000000000E+0   72.060087400E+0 640.65172522E+0 249.66231891E+0 4.3228294528E+0 -1.7755344304E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
79.00000000000E+0   70.367732374E+0 604.87968655E+0 242.82421868E+0 4.4584355505E+0 -1.7755344304E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
79.50000000000E+0   70.436428002E+0 599.82698515E+0 243.16328398E+0 4.5051177609E+0 -713.11323154E-3        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
80.00000000000E+0   71.153818237E+0 605.84844842E+0 242.00369667E+0 4.4350388401E+0 561.31370248E-3     CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
```

Comment: Happy to help.  Please help us help you.  Please provide the data as *text*, (it’s very difficult to copy/paste testing data from an image) and please show the expected output.

Comment: As mentioned previously, please also show the expected output.  Will the output be an list / array, or should it be stored into a file for archiving / later use?

Comment: need sufficient code for a minimum reproducable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: By the way: whenever possible (it is for example the case for Python error messages) provide in the future always the **text** and not an image of the text in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the `file_read` function returning a list of tuples with the required data as float values:

```
def file_read(fname):
    content_array = []
    is_data_line = False
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            # print(line)
            if is_data_line: 
                content_array.append( ( float(line[0:18]), float(line[36:52]) ) )
            else: 
                if line == "[TableValues]\n":
                    is_data_line = True
        return content_array

print( file_read('test.txt') )
# [(20.0, 276.1811286), (20.5, 307.54523316), (21.0, 342.74884502), (21.5, 380.91142586), (22.0, 419.46526145), (22.5, 446.71239183), (23.0, 457.14713254), (23.5, 445.55364407), (24.0, 387.30936661), (24.5, 319.64432623), (25.0, 244.65888941), (25.5, 198.29465134), (26.0, 179.98611383), (26.5, 180.56476209), (27.0, 187.95331936), (27.5, 204.93304827), (28.0, 229.36703471), (28.5, 255.05685484), (29.0, 275.11356206), (29.5, 296.39167426), (30.0, 310.54389797), (30.5, 309.1163666), (31.0, 318.64051843), (31.5, 321.71847396), (32.0, 316.03559512), (32.5, 325.35388729), (33.0, 325.79768947)]
```

In Python you can get a substring of a string with following syntax: `line[0:18]` . It gives a string with the first 18 characters of the line. The first character in a string has in Python the index `0`, `0:18` gives 18 characters not 19 because in Python the character with index 18 is not included in the substring addressed with `[0:18]`.

**Update because of in question not reported option of data line format in test.txt**

```
def file_read(fname):
    content_array = []
    is_data_line = False
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if is_data_line: 
                line = line.split()
                content_array.append( (float(line[0]),float(line[2])) )
            else: 
                if line == "[TableValues]\n":
                    is_data_line = True
        return content_array

print( file_read('test.txt') )
```

Generally to avoid possible problems with mixing usage of tabs and spaces separating columns in lines with data and also problems with varying width of columns another approach of extracting values from data lines by splitting the line into a list of strings on all white-space characters is needed. The above updated code uses this approach that will work also if a tab occurs between column one and two and with another width of the float numbers in the data lines.

Comment: It works for the table of 32 elemnts,, but not with the table of 80 elements.

Comment: Use: `content_array.append( ( float(line[0:18]), float(line[36:52].split('\t')[0]) ) )` . See updated code.

Comment: I am most gratefull. Thank you, thank you, thank you

Comment: Generally to avoid possible problems with mixing usage of tabs and spaces you can use another approach of extracting values from data lines by splitting the line into a list of strings on all white-space characters. Now the updated code uses this approach that will work also if a tab occurs between column one and two and with another width of the float numbers in the data lines.